# Is there any regedit value to set the sound change on VOL_UP/VOL_DOWN click

Tags: windows, keyboard, operating-systems, windows-7, regedit

If I press the sound up on my keyboard the volume increases by 2 is there any way to change that from 2 to 1 or something else

I am using Windows 7 but the regedit key is pobably the same as in Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the keypresses are sent to the OS as APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP and APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_DOWN HID messages. These are then translated to calls to IAudioEndpointVolume::VolumeStepUp() or IAudioEndpointVolume::VolumeStepDown(); this is hardcoded to 51 steps.

Unfortunately it is possible only with third party software, or you click on the slider in the right corner below, that allows you to set the volume step-by-step or value-by-value